# Subtracting time in powershell

Tags: powershell, time, format

I use the following time code:

```
$time = [DateTime]::UtcNow | get-date -Format "yyyyMMddHH"
$m2=$time-02  # trying to subtract 2 hours
```

However, for times like 2021021701, subtracting 2 gives me 2021021699.  How can I have the time display in the correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform date *calculations*, operate on `[datetime]` ([`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime)) instances and use that type's methods, such as `.AddHours()`; only *after* that should you create the desired *string* representation:

```
# Get the current UTC time as a [datetime] instance.
$time = [DateTime]::UtcNow

# Subtract 2 hours.
$m2Time = $time.AddHours(-2)

# Create the desired string representation.
$m2 = Get-Date $m2Time -Format 'yyyyMMddHH'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way.  The 2nd arg can be a datetime or a timespan.  $time is a datetime.

```
$time = get-date 
$m2 = $time - [timespan]'2:0'
$m2

Wednesday, February 17, 2021 7:31:59 PM
```